# when playback audio I need to show timer using flutter sound

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-streambuilder

In my chat app I added a feature to record audio using [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) package. Now I need to show timer when user playback that record. It worked fine before dart migration and before the package update. Now I can't get it to work.

Here is the code after the package update and after the migration to null safety.

```
void _addListeners(messageProvider) {
cancelPlayerSubscriptions();
_playerSubscription = _myPlayer?.onProgress!.listen((e) {
  print('test inside');
  if (e != null) {
    debugPrint('playback position here');
    maxDuration = e.duration as double;
    if (maxDuration <= 0) maxDuration = 0.0;

    var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        int.parse(e.position.toString()),
        isUtc: true);
    String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_GB').format(date);
    messageProvider.playerText = txt.substring(0, 8);
    if (int.parse(e.position.toString()) == maxDuration) {
      messageProvider.currentIcon = 0;
    }
  }
});
}
```

This is the code before the dart migration and package update

```
void _addListeners(messageProvider) {
cancelPlayerSubscriptions();
_playerSubscription = playerModule.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((e) {
  if (e != null) {
    maxDuration = e.duration;
    if (maxDuration <= 0) maxDuration = 0.0;

    DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        e.currentPosition.toInt(),
        isUtc: true);
    String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_GB').format(date);
    messageProvider.playerText = txt.substring(0, 8);
    if (e.currentPosition.toInt() == maxDuration) {
      messageProvider.currentIcon = 0;
    }
  }
});
}
```

my main problem is not printing 'test inside'. That means it's not going inside that. Any of you guys have an idea about this?